# Code-generation solution for Angular NgRx App

Tags: angular, webstorm, code-generation, ngrx, angular-schematics

I am currently developing an angular-ngrx app. I am using angular-cli to scaffold the app.
My trouble is as my app is growing larger i need to add lot of files eg
reducer, action , state, effects files . I want to automate this part, where I could generate these state management files with some boiler plate code.
Can I please get some help to begin with it?

Comment: https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/schematics/README.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can install `@ngrx/schematics` in your dependencies, then create new feature's `actions/reducers/effects` via `ng generate`

  https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/schematics/README.md
- If you're using WebStorm latest version, the IDE can recognize the installed schematics and let you create new `actions/reducers/effects`

  [image: new via Angular CLI]

  [image: Available items]
- Another handy feature of WebStorm is the Live Template, in the below screenshot, I wrote my own NgRx collection:

  [image: Live template]